# react native text component moving when checkbox is checked

Tags: react-native, checkbox, text

when this checkbox is checked, the adjacent text is moved slightly to the right, as the checkbox pixel count expands, presumably. Given that the ´position´ property is so limited in react native. How do it stop this from happening?

```
 <View style={this.props.checkBoxWrapper}>
    <CheckBox
     title={''}
     checked={this.state.checkedNews}
     onPress={() => this.setState({ checkedNews:!this.state.checkedNews })}
     containerStyle={this.props.checkboxContainerStyle}
     checkedColor='white'
     />
    <Text style={this.props.checkBoxTextStyle}>
    {I18n.t(this.props.labels.checkBoxNewsDialog)}
    </Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: Assuming that you're using the native Checkbox, that should not happen, maybe there's a problem with your styling. Try removing the `containerStyle`, and what's `checkedColor` prop? The native Checkbox element doesn't have any of these props